# AttributeError: 'Queue' object has no attribute 'items' in Eclispse

Tags: python, eclipse, queue

Why this given error in Eclispse?? 
I run this program in IDlE python it works perfect

```
class Queue:
  def _init_(self):
    self.items = []
  def isEmpty(self):
    return self.items == []
  def enqueue(self, item):
    self.items.insert(0,item)
  def dequeue(self):
    return self.items.pop()
  def size(self):
    return len(self.items)

  q = Queue()
  q.enqueue(1)
  q.enqueue(2)
  q.enqueue(3)
  print(q.size())
```

Comment: Is Eclipse configured correctly?